# $scope.$apply() creating multiple instances of a new scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with a provider and factory set up in angular, and in the factory is where I do all the heavy lifting of generating the templates, creating the instances, and doing all of the animations. The provider creates a very nifty slider menu from the left.

**Problem**

What's happening though, is that after the first instance of the slider menu, menu options start to double themselves. So I'll have the original 5, then 10, then 20, then 40... I have found a solution where we start with a null instance, and check if that instance is null, if it is null render the menu. So that forces it to only continuously render the initial 5, but then if we dynamically change the menu we won't ever see those changes and that is not what we want.

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Mr_Pikachu/chdbxt1h/351/

**Broken Code**

This is the chunk of code that I am most focused on, as it is the bit that is causing us the issue.

```
    backdropScope.close = function(){
        $animate.leave(menu).then(function(){
            backdrop.remove();
            //menuOpts.scope.$destroy();
            // menu_rendered = null;
            menu.remove();
        });
    }

    // menustack object
    $menuStack = {
        'open': function(menuOpts){
            menuOpts.scope.main = menuOpts.menu.main;
            if(!menu_rendered) {
                menu_rendered = menu_template(menuOpts.scope);
            }
            if(!backdropRendered) {
                backdropRendered = backdropTemplate(backdropScope);
            }
            menuOpts.scope.$apply(function(){
                $animate.enter(backdropRendered, body).then(function(){
                    $animate.enter(menu_rendered, body);
                });
            });
        }
    };
```

**List of Attempted Fixes**

- setting `menu_rendered = null` in the `$animate.leave()` will work on the first instance, and re-render the menu properly, but then the backdrop instance won't recognize a click event
- Using `menuOpts.scope.$destory()`, but it did absolutely nothing
- Using the current solution of `menu_rendered` check. It is not optimal and looking for a solution that allows the use of dynamic content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/chdbxt1h/355/

I moved the `angular.element` calls into the body of the `$menuStack.open` method. The menu content does not get duplicated in repeated exposures.  Presumably, this is because the DOM Node is created anew on each open, and garbage collected cleanly on `leave` and/or `remove`.

Both the background (menu-overlay) and menu are re-created on each open, so this should honor changes in the source menu data, though possibly not while the menu is open.